# call php after field validation

Tags: php, javascript, post

I am using JavaScript function in my `register page` to check whether all the fields in register page are filled or not.

I am using Form

```
    <form name="regform" onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit(this)"  method="post" >
  coding here......
    </form>
```

onsubmit i call my javascript function `validateFormOnSubmit(this)` as shown above.
now if all fields are collect means `All fields are filled correct`

now i want to post my this page on other page like `index.php` how it possible.

my java-script alert like that

```
function validateFormOnSubmit(theForm) {
var reason = "";
  reason += validatereferrer(theForm.referrer);
  reason += validateEmail(theForm.email);
  reason += validatePassword(theForm.pw1, theForm.pw2);
  reason += validatebuisinessname(theForm.buisinessname);

  if (reason != "") {
    alert("Please fix the following error(s) and resubmit:\n\n" + reason);
    return false;
  }

  alert("All fields are filled correctly");

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `action` on the form to be the page you want to forward to. Also ensure that `validateFormOnSubmit()` returns `false` if the validation fails so that the `POST` request is aborted. It should also return `true` if the validation is a success.

For example:

```
<form action="/index.php" 
      name="regform" 
      onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit(this)"
      method="post">
  coding here......
</form>
```

Comment: Does your validation function return `true` like I mentioned above? Please clarify what `after alert` means in your comment above.

Answer (score 1):

write `return true` after validation or `document.getElementByTagName('form')[0].submit()`

Answer (score 1):

## JQuery to the rescue:

the easiest and safe way to do this with Jquery is to use [Bassistance.de JQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

### Using your own code:

you simply set the action attribute of the form to the PHP page that handles the form and the javascript function that is used onsubmit should return true on success and the form will be submitted if something is wrong then you simply return false and show the errors.

Like this:

```
function validate_form() {
if (from_is_valid()) {
    return true;
}

else {
    ShowErrors();
    return false;
     }
}
```

### Your HTML

```
 <form name="regform" onsubmit="validate_form();"  method="post" action="PHP_File_That_Handles_the_form.php">
  coding here......
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
<form name="regform" onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit(this)" method="post" action="index.php" >
```

HTH :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the 'action' attribute to your form, like this:

```
<form name="regform" onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit(this)"  method="post" action='script.php' >
```

Where script.php is the path to your php script.